# PHP Account Registration Confirmation E-mail Code Not Confirming

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement, get

I am trying to complete the registration process of a user onto my website. The confirmation email with the activation link sends correctly. However when I click on the activation link I can only ever get the result "Error, looks like you were trying to do something out of the ordinary. Please contact us", which was supposed to be reserved when people are trying to mess around with the result etc.
The SQL query I wrote was intended to transfer a person who had registered their information, but had not yet activated their account from a 'tempusers' table to a 'users' table. This would happen once they click the link in the email.
I cannot see where my logic is wrong and why when there is a registered user in the 'tempusers' table this record isn't being picked up. This is my activation.php code. All and any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match(
'/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email'])){
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
}

if(isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key'])==32)){
$key = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key']);
}

if(isset($email) && isset($key)){
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM tempusers WHERE (email='$email' AND activation='$key') LIMIT 1 ")
or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($row['user_id']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($row['username']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($row['email']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($row['password']);
}

$result1 = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO users (user_id,username,email,password,role,credits)
VALUES ('','$username','$email','$password','user',0)") or die(mysql_error());

$result2 = mysql_query(" DELETE FROM tempusers WHERE user_id='$user_id' ") or die(mysql_error());

if(!$result1){
    echo "Oops your account could not be activated, please contact the system admin team!";
}else{
    header( 'Location:prompt.php?x=0' );
}
}else{
echo "Error, looks like you were trying to do something out of the ordinary. Please contact us";
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* queries, go for PDO or mysqli_*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of following 4 is false

```
(isset($_GET['email'])  or 

preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email']) or

(isset($_GET['key']) or 

(strlen($_GET['key'])==32))
```

Assuming you have **email** and **key** set in url for get and most likely you are 100% certain that there is key variable in get and it will have 32 characters, then that leaves to only **preg_match** where must be the error. It is also likely that the email could be url encoded. Make sure that when have expected value in $_GET['email'] by printing it out. If it is not what you expected you might want to sanitize it...